# Python, opening TarFile from data in a variable

Tags: python, tar

I get a tar file in the body of a http post request and I want to extract the contents without first writing the tar file to disc. The file used to be a zip file and i could do

```
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO(request.content.read()))
zip.extractall(some_path)
```

How do i do the same thing using tarfile.TarFile?

I tried

```
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj = StringIO(self.request.content.read()))
```

but got the error message:

```
file could not be opened successfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `fileobj` parameter to [`tarfile.open`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html).

**Edit:** I tried the following:

```
# t.py
import tarfile
import StringIO

tarf = open('test.tar', 'rb')
tarstrio = StringIO.StringIO(tarf.read())
tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=tarstrio)

tar.list()
```

and it worked as expected.

Comment: I tried it but didnt get it to work. I updated my question whit the info

Comment: It's possible the content is invalid. To test that, write it to a file and then validate it with `tar tf ...` on the command line.

Comment: You where right about the content being invalid. With valid data it works.